# ubuntu-15.04 Internet connection must be selected and password entered each time I reboot

Tags: networking, 15.04

While traveling, I bought Ubuntu magazine with 15.04 DVD attached.
I installed it in the motel room.  I seemed to work great.
I am now back home.
Each time I reboot my laptop, I must select the internet connection and reenter the password.
How can I make this permanent?
I will be using it in other locations, but want my home connection to be automatic.

Comment: Are you using WiFi or wired connection at home?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the two arrows from near the upper right corner of your desktop, you'll see all the possible internet connections.  Click on "edit connections" from the bottom of the menu.  Click your connection and choose EDIT. Click the GENERAL tab and you'll see the option to REMEMBER a connection as well as other options to set.  Hope that helps!  PS:  The two arrows might look like a WIRELESS ICON, if you are using wireless.  I'm sorry I didn't mention that first.  It's two arrows if you are wired and the WIRELESS symbol if you are connecting wirelessly.  Mouse over all the icons and you'll find it.